# explaining clasification models in mlr3 with DALEX

Tags: r, mlr3, dalex

I like to use the DALEX package in mlr3 and I tried to work with an example similar to chapter 9.2.4 in the mlr3 book (https://mlr3book.mlr-org.com/interpretation.html).

So my code looks like this

```
# the "learner_analyzed" is a classification forest
learner_analyzed$train(taskdata$task)


learner_exp = explain_mlr3(learner_analyzed,
  label    = "Ranger CF",
  colorize = FALSE)
```

I do not specify `data`  and `y`  as the help function in R studio tells me that this is not necessary for a fitted learner.

It seems though, that I cannot get the explanation to work and that it does not recognize I have a classification instead of a regression task. I get the following message with warnings:

> Preparation of a new explainer is initiated   -> model label       :
> Ranger CF    -> no data avaliable! (  WARNING  )   -> target variable
> :  not specified! (  WARNING  )   -> predict function  :
> yhat.GraphLearner  will be used (  default  )   -> predicted values  :
> No value for predict function target column. (  default  )   ->
> model_info        :  package mlr3 , ver. 0.13.0 , task classification
> (  default  )    -> model_info        :  Model info detected
> classification task but 'y' is a NULL .  (  WARNING  )   -> model_info
> :  By deafult classification tasks supports only numercical 'y'
> parameter.    -> model_info        :  Consider changing to numerical
> vector with 0 and 1 values.   -> model_info        :  Otherwise I will
> not be able to calculate residuals or loss function.   -> residual
> function :  difference between y and yhat (  default  )   A new
> explainer has been created!

What can I do here? I did not find a hint neither in the book not in the help function.

Comment: The error message says that you haven't given it any data -- have you tried that?

Comment: Thank you - I did not specify the data as I thought the help function would recommend this. 
It seems that I found a solution if I handle classification tasks a little bit different. Not so obvious but described in another documentation file: https://rdrr.io/cran/DALEXtra/man/explain_mlr3.html